# Creating a While Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm attempting to write a list of primes until my list exceeds a certain size.

What I currently have is this:

```
list = []
i = 2
while len(list) <= 10000:
    if prime(i) == 0:
    list.append(i)
i = i+1

print(list[-1])
```

where prime (x) is a prime function.

However this just makes python print out 0's and 1's in a seemingly infinite loop , I also tried putting i = 2 inside the while loop but that just printed 10,001 2's.

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong and please explain what it is about while loops I'm not quite understanding,
thank you

Comment: Fix your indentation, it looks like it got messed up when you copied the question.

Comment: Does `prime()` really return `0` instead of `True` when the number is prime?

Comment: Like @Barmar said, you need to indent everything under the **if** statement except for the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your `prime` function, so it is not possible to know if that is causing the problem. Consider posting the code to it. Otherwise:

I have changed the variable name `list` to `primes`. `list` is a built in function name within Python and it can sometimes cause problems using it as a variable name.

```
primes = []
i = 2
while len(primes) <= 10000:
    if prime(i) == 0:
        # Line here is indented further
        primes.append(i)
    # Line here is indented further
    i += 1

print(primes)
print(primes[-1])
```

How does that do? It looks like your problem was caused by a lack of proper indentation. Notice the changes to the lines underneath your while loop.

Edit:

> However this just makes python print out 0's and 1's in a seemingly infinite loop

It makes sense that the while loop would go on forever if your indentation was as written in your original answer. The fact that its output changes between 0 and 1 is weird, as technically the only input value would have been i = 2. Try the implementation as in this post, and see if your function prime works.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I actually did try to run the code - but as we don't have the function `prime`, I was unable to do so. The `len(list)` was an oversight simply corrected. Though I do appreciate your making the corrections - please consider being less quick to cast out assumptions.

Comment: yes I'm sorry, I am very much against "here is the working code" type answers and - as I just found out - quick to harshly judge the people who post them (will try to keep myself in check from now on :)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Nah man you're cool you're cool we good! You were right: it did need explanation, and it is no good to post "half" answers that don't quite work.